# Check if object is Byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to check if the object is `byte[]` using a reflection? I use this line of code to check `typeof(T).GetType().Equals(typeof(byte[]))` but it didn't work it out for me.  Is this achievable?

```cs
public static SetSqlDbType<T>()
{
    switch(Type.GetTypeCode(typeof(T)))
    {
        case TypeCode.Int64:
            return SqlDbType.BigInt;
        // ... some more cases
        case TypeCode.Object:
        {
            if (typeof(T).GetType().Equals(typeof(byte)))
            {
                return SqlDbType.VarBinary;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us a not working example.

Comment: You can also use `==` instead of  `Equals` here. However that will probably not solve the issue, which we don´t know unless you provide what you´ve trie and how it does not work.

Comment: it works just fine for me @HimBromBeere. its just that the `GetType()` thingy made the issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code:

```
typeof(T).GetType()
```

returns you type of *Type* :)

You can check this much more simplier

```
typeof(T) == typeof(byte[])
```

Comment: Thank you, I never that that `GetType()` thingy made the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `GetType()`:

```
public static bool f<T>(T x) => typeof(T).Equals(typeof(byte[]));
```